# Howto create or change SSRS2016 default palettes?

Tags: reporting-services, rdl, palette, ssrs-2016

I need to define my company-branded color palette for SSRS. This should be re-usable over several reports. I realized that I sometimes need to redefine the custom palette again and again, sometimes even on different controls in the same report, but always on a new report. I know I could copy and paste the colors in the RDL file but I want to avoid that
So I wondered since I know we can write extensions for reporting services, if there is a chance to change or create one of the default color palettes that already are shipped with ssrs? I looked around to find their definition on the Reporting Server but no luck. Anyone knows more?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to change the default palettes in SSRS or even add a new one that can be used.

The most helpful thing I found to do was to create a custom palette in one chart. Then you can use that same custom palette in other charts. You can copy and paste the chart into new reports to use the same palette or make a template report with the chart (and the custom colors in it).

http://clarkcreations.net/blog/5-simple-things-i-always-forget-about-ssrs-custom-color-palette/

My current problem with using the custom palette is that the border has to be the same color as the fill color. This doesn't work with my new color scheming with dark borders and light fills:
[image: pic]

Comment: Saving a sample with a custom palette as a report template file is my current solution which I was hoping to get rid of. I think you may be able to solve your issue by using a user defined function and assign colors to series and series' borders with two seperate functions that deliver a dark and a bright color based on a group name... see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2373/how-to-handle-empty-values-in-a-line-chart-in-ssrs/ But this requires you to add a function call to the COLOR and the BORDERCOLOR property of each series...

Answer (score 1):

I've got around this by creating a table in the database with the 9 corporate colour schemes included.  I've also adapted the default report template so that it includes a dataset called "Palette" for the colours.  I then just use `=First(Fields!Official,"Palette")` as an expression for the colours where needed.  I also have to change the colours for staff with particular visual needs so using this I can select the scheme appropriate for the staff member whilst having the official palette used in other cases.